# Linq Union: How to add a literal value to the query?

Tags: c#, linq, union

I need to add a literal value to a query.  My attempt

```
var aa = new List<long>();
aa.Add(0);
var a = Products.Select(p => p.sku).Distinct().Union(aa);

a.ToList().Dump(); // LinqPad's way of showing the values
```

In the above example, I get an error:

```
"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation
of query operators except the Contains() operator."
```

If I am using Entity Framework 4 for example, **what could I add to the Union statement to always include the "seed" ID?**

I am trying to produce SQL code like the following:

```
select distinct ID
from   product
union
select 0 as ID
```

So later I can `join` the list to itself so I can find all values where the next highest value is not present (finding the lowest available ID in the set).

**Edit:  Original Linq Query to find lowest available ID**

```
var skuQuery = Context.Products
               .Where(p => p.sku > skuSeedStart && 
                           p.sku < skuSeedEnd)
               .Select(p => p.sku).Distinct();

var lowestSkuAvailableList = 
    (from p1 in skuQuery
     from p2 in skuQuery.Where(a => a == p1 + 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where p2 == 0  // zero is default for long where it would be null
     select p1).ToList();
var Answer = (lowestSkuAvailableList.Count == 0 
              ? skuSeedStart : 
              lowestSkuAvailableList.Min()) + 1;
```

This code creates two SKU sets offset by one, then selects the SKU where the next highest doesn't exist.  Afterward, it selects the minimum of that (lowest SKU where next highest is available).

For this to work, the seed must be in the set joined together.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your query is being turned entirely into a LINQ-to-SQL query, when what you need is a LINQ-to-SQL query with local manipulation on top of it.

The solution is to tell the compiler that you want to use LINQ-to-Objects *after* processing the query (in other words, change the extension method resolution to look at `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`). The easiest way to do this is to tack `AsEnumerable()` onto the end of your query, like so:

```
var aa = new List<long>();
aa.Add(0);
var a = Products.Select(p => p.sku).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Union(aa);

a.ToList().Dump(); // LinqPad's way of showing the values
```

Comment: The code ultimately gets the lowest ID available no less than "seed".  Currently, it gets the lowest ID starting at some existing ID.  Thus why the "0" needs to be part of the query.  In SQL, I do `select distinct ID from Product union select 0 as ID` (I added distinct to clarify it selects distinct values)

Comment: @Dr. Zim: I don't believe it's possible to introduce an actual literal value like this into the LINQ-to-SQL query. If you can post your query in its larger context, we may be able to find another way to skin the cat, but as a general rule, it's not possible.

Comment: Added the original Linq query :)

Answer (score 1):

Up front: not answering exactly the question you asked, but solving your problem in a different way.

How about this:

```
var a = Products.Select(p => p.sku).Distinct().ToList();

a.Add(0);

a.Dump(); // LinqPad's way of showing the values
```

Comment: I added the original Linq query that will better explain why I couldn't pull the whole set of SKUs locally.

Answer (score 1):

You should create database table for storing constant values and pass query from this table to Union operator.

For example, let's imagine table "Defaults" with fields "Name" and "Value" with only one record ("SKU", 0).

Then you can rewrite your expression like this:

```
        var zero = context.Defaults.Where(_=>_.Name == "SKU").Select(_=>_.Value);
        var result = context.Products.Select(p => p.sku).Distinct().Union(zero).ToList();
```